Complexity of optimal cartesian matching
Question:

what is known about the algorithmic aspects of optimally matching a set $\mathcal{P} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \left(1,\,\cdots,\,k_i\right)$ of grid-points to a set of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^nk_i$ function values?
Regarding the cost-function let this question be focussed on $\min\left( \sum\limits_{\underset{p,q\in\mathcal{P}}{p-q=e_j}}\left|f(p)-f(q)\right|\right)$ where $e_j$ is some unit vector, that is the summation is over all absolute deltas of the values of the immediate neighbors in the principal directions

